# Change default icons in BlazorApp

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor

Friends,

I need help changing the default icons in Blazor.

[image: default icons in Blazor]

Comment: Try https://github.com/justdmitry/FullEmojiList and enjoy colored icons without extra dependencies :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your project go to: `Pages-> Shared -> NavMenu.razor` and look for the following code:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
    <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
</NavLink>
```

Change the `span` class value to replace the icons.

Comment: How can i remove about on App?

Comment: @questionmark go to `MainLayout.razor` and remove the anchor link.